# jquery sending form in not showing in firebug

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request, firebug

I want to know if it is possible to send `ajax` data and prevent that from being logged in tools like FireBug.

I send my data like this:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var value = $("#value");
    var valuePost = value.val(); 
    $.post("submit.php", {value: valuePost},
    function(data){} 
    , "html");
});
```

But when this is sent, then tools like FireBug capture that data. I do not want that, because I am sending passwords. Is there any way to prevent tools like FireBug from capturing the send data?

Comment: Please show your code...

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Could you re-write it?

Comment: ready, gave an improved, now let's see if the understanding.

Comment: @LeoBC It still makes no sense at all... Is the problem that the data you're submitting appears in tools like FireBug? Which you don't want to happen. Or is the problem that you're **trying** to send data, which isn't showing up in FireBug...?

Comment: Therefore, the data that I am sending are appearing in tools like firebug, it would appear that a hundred.

Comment: because the data are sent privileged data such as password ..

Comment: @LeoBC I see what you mean. You don't want FireBug or any other tool to capture the data you're sending from an HTML page. That's simply not possible. It will ALWAYS show up in tools like that. The best thing you can do is use an encryption like `https` (SSL).

Comment: **@w00** more, with sending ("https", "ssl"), the data are hidden in encrypted firebug?

Comment: @LeoBC No, because firebug captures it **before** it is encrypted and sent. But anyone else that is sniffing your network will get the encrypted data. So with others words, if you use SSL, you don't have to worry about FireBug.

Comment: **@w00** and the "curl", could not be sending data multiple times? it would not be legal even put captcha at login time by accessing the firebug can see the page sent and then send alert by curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it as an answer:

When you send data from a webpage, then tools like FireBug will always be able to capture what is send. When you don't use an encryption like `https` (SSL), then FireBug shows the data as how it will be send.

If you DO use an encryption like `https`, then FireBUg will still be able to capture and show the data that will be sent, in a readable format. But you don't have to worry about that. FireBug is just a "local" tool to help you out. So you can see what is happening on that webpage. When the data is actually sent (over the internet), then it will then be encrypted.

Nnyone that is sniffing your network will see the encrypted data and not the data that you see in FireBug.

So don't worry about tools like FireBug. That's just merely there to help you (as a local user) out. Just use SSL if you want to sent important data over the internet, like passwords and such.